# How to reliably get LOGON USER name/sid from a process running as SYSTEM?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, winapi

I have an app that runs (on the interactive desktop) as SYSTEM. The app needs to start a browser or email client *AS THE CURRENTLY LOGGED-IN USER*.

I thought I could just go look at the desktop, windows station, or session, and be able to determine which user's logon desktop I was running in. However, when I got user information from desktop, windows station, and session, they all seemed to be special accounts (e.g. "LogonSessionId_0_4005652").

The one approach that seemed promising was calling `WTSQuerySessionInformationW(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, WTS_CURRENT_SESSION, WTSUserName, ...)`. That yielded the logon user's name, and I could call `LookupAccountNameW()` to get the SID.

This bit from Microsoft's documentation on WTSQuerySessionInformationW makes me a bit uncomfortable though...

> Retrieves session information for the specified session on the specified *Remote Desktop Session Host (RD Session Host) server*.  (emphasis mine)

...and also...

> If Remote Desktop Services is not running, calls to WTSQuerySessionInformation fail.

I seem to remember that the "Home" editions of previous Windows releases *didn't support Remote Desktop*. Our app targets Windows 10 and 11. Can I be **certain** that the `WTSQuerySessionInformationW` call will work for all users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ProcessIdToSessionId` on yourself and then `WTSQueryUserToken` should give you a token you can use with `CreateProcessAsUser`.

Another alternative is `FindWindow` to find the taskbar and duplicate the Explorer.exes token. This will not work if Explorer is not running.

Comment: re: "on yourself", remember that I'm running as SYSTEM (Local System), so any attempts to get the user from my process, etc, will return SYSTEM.  But, I'll try this again.

Comment: That is just to get the session id.

Comment: Well color me surprised. I could swear I'd tried this, but it works like a charm. Thank you VERY much!